# AWS S3 Upload Using Signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWS provides SDKs on iOS and Android to upload to their servers yet you don't want your key exposed if it was decompiled. How do you prevent that? Is there a way to sign a URL on the backend and give it to the client so they can upload directly onto S3 Without exposing the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Amazon STS (Security Token Service)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/Welcome.html) to generate unique sign-in credentials that also expire automatically.

You can also control permissions on these temporary credentials obtained via STS (for example to allow only upload permissions in a certain S3 bucket).

Comment: Is there a way I get generate one via rails?

Comment: There's an AWS SDK for Ruby. Check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/STS.html

Comment: Thanks I'll investigate this!

Comment: So am I supposed to make an IAM user with certain security parameters and provide session tokens to each of my clients with those tokens when needed?